# integrating a square in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I work on the following problem. Would love feedback to know if I'm on the right track.

Problem:

> Let $γ_{N}$ be the positively oriented square centered at $0$ with sides of length
> $(2N + 1)π,$ for an integer $N ≥ 0.$ Prove that there exists a positive, real constant $C$
> such that$$\forall z ∈ γ_{N}\quad\left|\sin z\right| ≥ C.$$

My initial ideas:

Use Cauchy's integral formula that states that for a holomorphic function $f(z)$ and a closed curve $C,$ we have:

$$f(a) =\frac{1}{2 \pi i} ∮_C \frac{f(z)}{z-a} dz$$

where $∮_C$ denotes the contour integral around the closed curve $C$ and $a$ is any point inside $C.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Contour doesn’t help since nothing stops it from being near zero at a single point on the curve. Squares are simple, so try explicitly looking at what sin evaluates to on the edges.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Recall that if $z = x + i y$, with $x, y \in \Bbb R$, then
$$\sin z = \sin x \cosh y + i \cos x \sinh y .$$ Now, consider the vertical and horizontal edges separately.

> Along the vertical edges, $\sin x = \pm 1$ and $\cos x = 0$, so $\sin z = \pm \cosh y$, hence $|\sin z| = \cosh y \geq 1$.

> Along the horizontal edges,\begin{align}|\sin z|^2 &= \cosh^2 (2 N + 1) \pi \sin^2 x + \sinh^2 (2 N + 1) \pi \cos^2 x \\ &\geq \sinh^2 (2 N + 1) \pi \sin^2 x + \sinh^2 (2 N + 1) \pi \cos^2 x \\ &=\sinh^2(2N + 1)\pi \end{align}